# c# textbox sets value and edited not save

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have on Textbox, where I load text from db then edit and save, but when I set TextBox2.Text in BindTextBox, and I finish edit it, it has same value in InsertToDatabase like in BindTexBox method it does not metter i edited it or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindTextBox
    }


    protected void BindTextBox()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Globals.DatabaseConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.Search", myConnection);
        string message = "";
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = Utility.qID;
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            message = reader["Description"].ToString();            
        }
        myConnection.Close();
        TextBox2.Text = message;
    }

    protected void InsertToDatabse()
    {
        string text = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Globals.DatabaseConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.Insert", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = Utility.qID;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = text;
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertToDatabse();
        BindTextBox();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for if your page is postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      BindTextBox();
}
```

When you press your save button a postback to server is done and your load method is called again. This causes your textbox value to overridden since you call BindTextBox on both initial load and postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Check for postback before you call Bindtextbox() on pageload